# GLEW Linked Properly on One Project, but not Another (C++ with MinGW Make)

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, linker-errors

I have to be missing something here, and that's to be expected, since I just picked up C++ a little while ago.  But I was compiling a project using MinGW Make, and it always comes up with missing references for what I suspect is the GLEW library.  However, I have a project with almost identical settings that compiles just fine.  Admittedly, the problem code isn't mine, and it's eight years old, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Here's the working project's Makefile:

```
CXX = C:\MinGW\bin\g++
OBJ = main.o graphics.o 
TARGET = bin\helloWorld
LIBHEAD = C:\Cpp\glfw\include C:\Cpp\glew\include C:\Cpp\glm
LIBINCLUDE = C:\Cpp\glfw\lib-mingw C:\Cpp\glew\lib
LIBFILES = glfw3 gdi32 opengl32 glew32

HEADERS += $(LIBHEAD:%=-I%)
LDFLAGS += $(LIBINCLUDE:%=-L%)
LIBS += $(LIBFILES:%=-l%)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cc $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(HEADERS)
```

Here's the one that doesn't work:

```
CXX = C:\MinGW\bin\g++
OBJ = Main.o
TARGET = bin\demo
LIBHEAD = C:\Cpp\freeglut\include C:\Cpp\glew\include C:\Cpp\Tiff\include 
LIBINCLUDE = C:\Cpp\freeglut\lib C:\Cpp\glew\lib  C:\Cpp\Tiff\lib
LIBFILES = libtiff freeglut opengl32 glew32

HEADERS += $(LIBHEAD:%=-I%)
LDFLAGS += $(LIBINCLUDE:%=-L%)
LIBS += $(LIBFILES:%=-l%)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(HEADERS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Here's the output of that compilation.  There's a single warning during the compile, but it generates the object files just fine:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++ -c -o Main.o Main.cpp -IC:\Cpp\freeglut\include -IC:\Cpp\glew\include -IC:\Cpp\Tiff\include
Main.cpp: In function 'void loadData()':
Main.cpp:225:31: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     loadTIFF("earth.tiff", tex);
                               ^
C:\MinGW\bin\g++ -o bin\demo Main.o -LC:\Cpp\freeglut\lib -LC:\Cpp\glew\lib -LC:\Cpp\Tiff\lib -llibtiff -lfreeglut -lgdi32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglew32
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderiv'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderInfoLog'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x373): undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgram'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x37d): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
{{ And dozens of similar messages}}
```

This is driving me up the wall!  I've tried all sorts of things.  I tried inserting `#define GLEW_STATIC`, I tried linking `glu32`, `gdi32`, and `glfw3`.  I tried switching around the flag orders.  I tried rebuilding glew and linking *those* files.  I tried dragging glew32.dll directly into the project directory.  None of it changed anything.

But here's where it gets crazier: I tried searching for the references listed in the console, thinking that maybe their names would match function names in the code.  They don't.  Then I tried searching for the references online.  Google "`glewGetShaderiv`", with quotes and see what comes up.  **Nothing at all.**  Not one result.  It autocorrects to `glGetShaderiv`.  I tested the other references.  Most of them are the same way.  I don't know exactly how the linker sets the names for its references, but I somehow doubt all of these "gl"s were magically changed into "glew"s.

But even that might be a red herring, because glewInit() is among the unknown references!  I'm in way over my head here!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was!  So, with an installation of Perl I have, it included its own gcc and g++ (for some reason), and added these to the path.  When I compiled the GLEW library, I used these compilers.  However, as you'll notice in the makefiles, I specify the MinGW compiler.  In fact, when I tried to recompile my working project, it failed because **I had switched from the compiler in the path to the MinGW compiler**.  The compiler that came with Perl was 64-bit, and the MinGW compiler is 32 bit, so when the MinGW compiler tried to read the binaries compiled with the other compiler, it failed to find the correct references!  This just goes to show you that 99% of bugs are entirely human error.

Of course, now I have the problem of debugging seriously out of date OpenGL, but that's outside the scope of this question.